# Laço de Repetição no Tmemo

Tags: delphi

Estou utilizando um *Tmemo* que recebe dados de um edit,porem esse dado vai ser inserido x vezes, a questão é a seguinte:

Ao apertar o botão o *Tmemo* recebera os dados da seguinte maneira:

```
Memo1.Lines[10] := ('linha adicionada');
```

Gostaria que ao clicar no botão os edits fossem limpos, e ao a pessoa digitar os novos dados e ao apertar o mesmo botão, os dados fossem inseridos na linha abaixo no caso `Memo1.Lines[11]`. e assim repetidamente..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vem de inserir na posição `[10], [11]` por exemplo, use:

```
Memo1.lines.add('linha adicionada');
```

Assim sempre vai adicionar na próxima linha.

E para limpar seus `Edits` use:

```
edit1.clear;
```

Comment: Porem abaixo da linha [10] existem informações
e seu colocar o `Memo1.lines.add ('linha adicionada');`
e a pessoa não digitar nada, ficara o espaço em branco

Comment: No caso para esclarecermos sua duvida, você quer sempre adicionar uma linha nova acima da linha 10 ?

Comment: Embaixo da linha 10. clicando no mesmo botão na que a 10 foi criada.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima, poste seu código para esclarecer melhor sua pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: `Memo1.Lines.Add('    dose = ' + funcao);
Memo1.Lines.Add('    '+'if'+' '+ cond1+':');
Memo1.Lines.Add('        '+ enta1); `
Ao apertar o botão 1 vez, o Tmemo recebe esses dados
Gostaria que quando apertasse o mesmo botão, ele adicionasse informações na linha de baixo.

Comment: se você usar `Memo1.Lines.Add` ele irá adicionar na próxima linha.

Comment: Concordo totalmente, o problema é como faço para que quando eu apertar o botão X vezes, ele vá adicionado?

Comment: Usando `Memo1.Lines.Add` pois ele irá adicionar sempre no fim do `Memo1`. Independente de quantas vezes você clicar no botão.

Comment: Certo,  pense nesse cenário. Variável X recebe os dados de um edit, e essa variável é escrita no Tmemo. Após isso clicasse no botão o edit e a Variável X receberá novos valores. E deverá ser escrita embaixo da anterior.

Comment: x := edit1.text;
memo1.lines.add(x);

Pode clicar quantas vezes quiser ele sempre adicionará uma linha nova certinho.

Comment: Acho que não estou me explicando bem
Vou adicionar um exemplo real:
edit vai receber a seguinte string: k1 > 90 
após dar ok e escrever no memo a pessoa irá digitar
edit vai receber a seguinte string k1 = 100
essa string deve ser escrita abaixo de k1 > 90

Comment: Então, não sei onde você esta errando, pois com `memo1.lines.add();` terá um resultado igual ao que você espera.